# How is Enum is implemented internally and how to access constructor of an enum in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how Enum is implemented internally in java and I am trying with the below example

```
public enum MyEnum {
   MyEnum (){
    System.out.println("HelloWorld");   
    }
 }
```

As the above doesnot throw any compilation error I would like to know how to call the MyEnum() constructor.

Comment: The constructor is called when the enum instances are created. If you declare some instances inside your enum, each one will call the constructor.

Comment: You don't have to call it. It is called automatically when the members are initialized. As you don't presently have any members, it is never called. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The constructor for an enum type must be package-private or private access. It automatically creates the constants that are defined at the beginning of the enum body. You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself.

You can't access the constructor from outside of that enum. You can access it by actually defining an enum constant.

```
public enum Planet {

    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;
    private final double radius;

    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

For more examples on enums see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 2):

Java implements `enum` like a class extending `java.lang.Enum` as their base class. Most of its functionality comes from support of the Java compiler, which, among other things, ensure that you cannot instantiate `enum` classes with operator `new`, and that `enum` values are propertly constructed.

If you want to see `MyEnum`'s constructor called, add at least one `enum` value to it:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1;
    MyEnum (){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");   
    }
}
```

**Note:** While you can also use reflection to create "illegitimate" instances of the `enum`, this should not be done in any production-like settings, because it breaks assumptions about `enum` membership.

Answer (score 0):

`enum`s are special classes which are a generalization of singletons and provide one instance for each of the constants. Internally, the fields are treated as `public static final` with type same as `enum` in which they are defined. And, constructor of enum is treated as `private`, so you cannot call the `MyEnum()` constructor from outside the `enum MyEnum`. The constructor is used in cases where we want to have some property attached to the constants. For example, consider below:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VAL_A("First Value"),
    VAL_B("Second Value");

    private final String fullName;

    MyEnum(String fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

Then, we could do something like `MyEnum.VAL_A.getFullName();`

Answer (score 0):

Enum is implemented internally by using class concept. Every enum constant is implicitly declared as public static final. Enum constant is static so we can access it by using enum-name.

For  example:

```
enum Color{
    Red,Green,Blue; 
}
```

is internally implemented as :

```
final class Color extends java.lang.Enum { 
    public static final Color Red = new Color ();
    public static final Color Green= new Color ();
    public static final Color Blue= new Color ();
}
```

All enum constants will be created at the time of class loading automatically and hence constructor will be executed at the time of enum class loading for every enum constant. We can't create enum object explicitly and hence we can't invoke constructor directly.